# Global bool variable and template

Tags: c++, templates

In a c++ class i've a global bool variable *const_var* set in constructor and unchanged elsewhere; and there are many *if condition* on this variable in my class, to optimize code i  would like to use template es: **template < bool const_var>** and instance object with **X< true>**()

How can I do?
thank's

here a simple class without template:

.h file

```
class X {
public:
bool const_var;

X(bool b);
void method1();

void method2();
void method3();
};
```

.cpp file

```
X::X(bool b){
const_var=b; //unchanged elsewhere
}

void X::method1(){
 ...
 if(const_var==true)
 ...
 if(const_var==false)
 ...
}

void X::method2(){
 ...
 if(const_var==true)
 ...
 if(const_var==true)
 ...
}

void X::method3(){
 ...
 if(const_var==false)
 ...
 if(const_var==true)
  ...
}
```

Comment: `const_var` is not global at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the class definition into a class template definition:

```
template <bool const_var>
class X
{
public:
  X();
  void method1();
  void method2();
  void method3();
};
```

In the implementation, you will then do:

```
template <bool const_var>
X<const_var>::X() {}

template <bool const_var>
X<const_var>::method1()
{
  //...
  if (const_var)
  //...
  if (!const_var)
  //...
}

//dtto for method2 and method3
```

The `if`s will be optimised out by the compiler.

However, templates have to be explicitly instantiated, or their definition must be available in every translation unit using them. This means you must **either** move the function bodies into the header file, **or** add the following lines into the .cpp:

```
template class X<true>;
template class X<false>;
```

Also note that when you change `X` into a class template, `X` will no longer be a type; only `X<true>` and `X<false>` are types. This means you cannot, for example, declare a variable `X x1(true);`, it must be e.g. `X<true> x1;`.

Comment: one could also use template specialization to give X<const_var>::method1() different function bodies depending on const_var, it depends on the ratio of code in if statements to code common to both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think templates are best applied here. You've got an object that is pretending to be 2 different things based on a constant boolean. Why don't you break X up into 2 different objects?

```
class Thing
{
   public:
       virtual ~Thing(){}
       virtual method1() = 0;
       virtual method2() = 0;
       etc...
 };

 class TrueThing : public Thing
 {
    virtual method1(){//performs true branch}
    virtual method2(){//true branch}
 }
 class FalseThing : public Thing
 {
    virtual method1(){//performs false branch}
    etc...
 }

 void main()
 {
     TrueThing true_thing;
     FalseThing false_thing;
     true_thing.method1();
     false_thing.method1();
 }
```

Comment: The point of the question is to introduce optimisation, not overhead of virtual calls.